# Template-level subscription in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am using

```
Template.blogPost.onCreated(function() {
  var postId = FlowRouter.getParam('postId');
  self.subscribe('singlePost', postId);  
});
```

however, I have seen examples with

```
Template.blogPost.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
    var postId = FlowRouter.getParam('postId');
    self.subscribe('singlePost', postId);  
  });
});
```

What is the difference and which way is the preferred way to do it?

Comment: I think you mean `this.subscribe` in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

The second version is reactive to changes to the `postId` parameter in your route. Depending on how you have your routes defined in flow router, you may or may not create a new template each time you change that `postId` parameter. If you don't (and it would be good to try not to), then the second implementation will still update your subscription to be the presumably correct one for the parameter in the URL.

If you don't require that reactivity, e.g., because you re-create the template each time a new route is visited, then the first is fine. But really, even then there is no harm in using the second, other than perhaps the readability of the code.